# In a Geoserver Layer how do you make the color ramp smaller?

Tags: geoserver, wms

Is there a way to resize a color ramp decoration in a geoserver layer? As you can see in the WMS jpg request below the ramp overlaps my map.

I know how to anchor and move the color ramp, but ultimately I need to make it smaller.

[image: Color Ramp Too Large]

Here is my layout.xml I see the size="auto" but when I try to change it the ramp simply doesn't display.

```
<layout>
  <decoration type="text" affinity="bottom,left" offset="36,6">
    <option name="message" value="2016 Leaf Out"/>
    <option name="font-size" value="22"/>
    <option name="font-family" value="Arial"/>
    <option name="halo-radius" value="2"/>
  </decoration>
  <decoration type="legend" affinity="bottom,right" offset="6,-55" size="auto"/>
</layout>
```

Comment: You could use getlegendgraphic to fetch the legend and place it anywhere you want

Comment: @iant I have thought about fetching the legend separately, but ideally I want the legend to be embedded in the image straight from Geoserver.

Comment: May need to submit a patch then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `type="image"` instead of `type="legend"` and set the appropriate URL. You can control the result image a lot using `GetLegendGraphic` [request parameters](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html#get-legend-graphic).

Remember to use XML entity `&amp;` instead of `&` in the URL and to encode special characters with percents (e.g. a space character is `%20`).

An example:

```
<decoration type="image" affinity="top,left" offset="6,36" size="auto">
    <option name="url" value="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&amp;version=1.3.0&amp;request=GetLegendGraphic&amp;format=image%2Fpng&amp;width=16&amp;height=16&amp;layer=my_layer&amp;LEGEND_OPTIONS=fontSize:12;layout:vertical;dx:0.04;dy:0;mx:0.01;my:0.08;fontName:DejaVu%20Sans%20Mono;fontAntiAliasing:true;&amp;transparent=true"/>
</decoration>
```